# What is Haskell's style of polymorphism?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, polymorphism, type-systems

With Haskell's type classes it almost seems that it enables ad hoc polymorphism, but its functions declarations seem parametric polymorphism.  Am I mixing my understanding of different things?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Indeed, Haskell supports both (higher rank) parametric polymorphism, and ad hoc (or *bounded*) polymorphism. Parametric polymorphism in Haskell is supported via its Hindley-Milner/[System F](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F) type system. Ad hoc polymorphism is supported via type classes.

For the origin of type classes and ad hoc polymorphism, see Wadler's papers:

- [How to make ad-hoc polymorphism less ad hoc](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/class/class.ps.gz), Philip Wadler and Stephen Blott. 16'th Symposium on Principles of Programming Languages, ACM Press, Austin, Texas, January 1989.

For the origin of the distinction between parametric and ad hoc polymorphism, you can dig up Strachey's papers,

- C. Strachey, [Fundamental concepts in programming languages](http://www.itu.dk/courses/BPRD/E2009/fundamental-1967.pdf). Lecture notes for the International Summer School in Computer Programming, Copenhagen, August 1967

Comment: Sorry for naive questions, but does Haskell provide other forms of polymorphism too?

Comment: Not really. It doesn't have subtyping, which would be the main other form.

Comment: @Eli, Don I think it's worth mentioning that Haskell's type system supports higher-kinded polymorphism which is severely lacking in other statically typed languages. Higher-ranks are also typically a missing feature of other languages.

Comment: @snk_kid, while we're at it, UHC implements kind polymorphism, and it might be coming to GHC as well if byorgey's typekind work materializes. (NB: this is never used in practice (yet), but is very cool.)