# Is allowing untagged unions equivalent to allowing type classes?

Tags: haskell, type-theory, subtyping

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40620913/3032349) question, untagged unions are described as a form of subtyping.

Type classes are also a form of subtyping.

Are they conceptually equivalent? If they are, how would I implement these in Haskell?

Comment: I would argue that Haskell doesn't have subtyping as it would be traditionally defined because every value has exactly _one_ type. Typeclasses are simply a way of extending the language of types to allow for user-defined polymorphism. That is, it lets a value `x` have a type `C a => a` where `C` is a set of rules `a` must conform to; but still `x` has exactly one type. Contrast this with OOPy subtyping where a value `x` has multiple types: its base type, and any type that subclasses from the base type.

Comment: Another, more pedantic argument: subtyping would inhibit the DHM-style principal-type type inference that Haskell compilers have, whereas typeclasses do not.

Comment: To elaborate on @haoformayor's point: don't confuse subtyping and ad-hoc polymorphism. Subtyping is one flavour of ad-hoc polymorphism, and type classes are a rather different one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Type classes are also a form of subtyping.

They aren't. For the sake of illustration, let's return to the [TypeScript examples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) I alluded to [in that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40621884/2751851):

> If we have a value that has a union type, we can only access members
>   that are common to all types in the union.
>
> ```
> interface Bird {
>     fly();
>     layEggs();
> }
>
> interface Fish {
>     swim();
>     layEggs();
> }
>
> function getSmallPet(): Fish | Bird {
>     // ...
> }
>
> let pet = getSmallPet();
> pet.layEggs(); // okay
> pet.swim();    // errors
> ```

Here, the return type of `getSmallPet` is neither `Fish` nor `Bird`, but a supertype of both that has as members the members common to both `Fish` and `Bird`. A `Fish` is *also* a `Fish | Bird`, and so is a `Bird`.

What happens with type classes is quite different:

```
foo :: Num a => a -> a
foo x = (x * x) + x
```

While both `foo (3 :: Integer)` and `foo (7.7 :: Double)` work, that does not mean there is a supertype corresponding to `Num` that `(3 :: Integer)` and `(7.7 :: Double)` also have. Rather, all that `Num a => a -> a` says is that your choice of `a` should have an instance of `Num` (and it is worth emphasising that `Num` is not a type), so that there are suitable implementations of `(*)` and `(+)` for your chosen type. Unlike OOP methods, `(*)` and `(+)` do not belong to any particular type, and so it is not necessary to introduce a supertype in order to use them with both `Integer` and `Double`.

Comment: This answer helps a lot, thank you. Nonetheless I have a feeling that the two concepts are at least related, as the `Pet` example can also be implemented via type classes. Phrased as a question: "Are type class constraints as powerful as untagged unions?" (Although this is probably more suited as a follow-up question).

Comment: @ThreeFx We might say that, in this case, they would be two very different ways of achieving the same goal. By the way, it is worth noting that the untagged aspect is not essential to the discussion -- if we had, in the TypeScript example, an `Oviparous` interface with a `layEggs` method that `Fish` and `Bird` would extend, the fundamental difference would remain the same. A relevant, if somewhat tangential, question: [*Parametric polymorphism vs Ad-hoc polymorphism*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6730126/2751851).

Comment: The way subsumption interacts with subclasses has a very subtype-like feel. If a function expects an argument of type `forall f. Applicative f => f a -> f b`, I can surely pass it one of type `forall f. Functor f => f a -> f b`. Now that does go beyond standard Haskell, but higher-rank types have been a significant part of real Haskell for a long time.

Comment: @dfeuer Indeed -- it is not without reason we explicitly talk in terms of subtyping when considering [the *lens* hierarchy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16.1). A postscript on that would be a worthwhile addition to this answer.

Comment: @duplode, by the way, I ran into something very much related yesterday, which made me realize (perhaps for the first time) that removing and reapplying a `newtype` constructor is not always a no-op. See [this PR](https://github.com/haskell/primitive/pull/146/files), which iteratively modifies functions by changing their constraints. In particular, `WonkP (runWonkP w)` is *not* `coerce w`.

Comment: @dfeuer Ooh, nice! If I'm reading it right, that's an impressively stealthy IfCxt-like trick.

Comment: @duplode, I prefer to think of the rule structure as a distant relative of the bundle trick in `vector`, but I guess the `IfCxt` thing is a translation to the world of overlapping instances.