# Bounded parametric polymorphism vs ad-hoc polymorphism

Tags: types, polymorphism

A similar question has already answered here - [Parametric polymorphism vs Ad-hoc polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6885445/2682729). The difference in this question is with the term *bounded*. It seems that there are two distinct flavors of ad-hoc polymorphism -

1. For example, in C++ you can write

   ```
   int foo(int x) { return x; }
   int foo(string x) { return x.size(); }
   ```

   In this case, it doesn't make sense to speak of the type of `foo` as an overload set (in the sense that it is not a user-definable type, or something for which you can create an alias), but it does make sense to speak of the types of the individual overloads themselves.
2. In Haskell, you can write

   ```
   class Foo a where
     foo :: a -> Int
   instance Foo Int where
     foo x = x
   instance Foo String where
     foo xs = length xs
   ```

   Here, it makes sense to speak about the type of `foo` by itself as a proper type `Foo a => a -> Int` which can be used like an ordinary user defined type.

Is it appropriate to say:

1. C++'s flavor of ad-hoc polymorphism via function overloading cannot be classified as bounded parametric polymorphism.
2. Haskell's flavor of ad-hoc polymorphism via type classes can be classified as bounded parametric polymorphism (as a different example, Pierce's *Types and Programming Languages* talks about System-F<sub><:</sub> in a similar context).

Is bounded parametric polymorphism a strict "subset" of ad-hoc polymorphism, in the sense that any type system that can be said to have the first can also be said to have the second?